# jQuery File not linking to HTML Document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's where i found the code which I'm editing for a project:
http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/43/#

When attempting to link the .js file, it doesn't load, creating one large image rather than the tile of images.

Cheers for all the help.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script type="text/jquery" href="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
           <div class="carousel">
              <div><img src="images/matt.png" /></div>
              <div><img src="img/i02.jpg" /></div>
              <div><img src="img/i03.jpg" /></div>
              <div><img src="img/i04.jpg" /></div>
              <div><img src="img/i05.jpg" /></div>
              <div><img src="img/i06.jpg" /></div>
              <div><img src="img/i07.jpg" /></div>
              <div><img src="img/i08.jpg" /></div>
              <div><img src="img/i09.jpg" /></div>
              <div><img src="img/i10.jpg" /></div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    min-height: 600px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
body * {
    font-family: Arial, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 22px;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: -250px 0 0 -400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper,
.carousel,
.carousel div,
.carousel div img {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
}
.carousel {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.carousel div {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.carousel div img {
    border: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}

/* after js */
.carousel div.thumb img {
    width: 160px;
    height: 100px;
    left: -30px !important;
    top: 0 !important;
}
```

Javascript (This is what it said on the website so it may be jQuery, but I'm not sure)

```
$(function() {
    //  cache first carousel
    var $org = $('.carousel');

    //  variables
    var width = 800,
        height = 500,
        cols = 8,
        rows = 5,
        $img = $org.children()
        imgs = $img.length;

    //  duplicate carouesl
    for( a = 0; a < rows * cols; a++ ) {
        $('#wrapper').append( $org.clone() );
    }

    //  cache all carousls
    $all = $('.carousel');
    $all.each(function( i ) {

        //  current row and column
        var row = Math.floor( i / cols ),
            col = i % cols;

        var $t = $(this),
            i2 = i % imgs,
            $x = $img.eq( i2 ).clone();

        //  first image -> thumbnail
        $x.addClass( 'thumb' );
        $t.prepend( $x );

        var $d = $t.children();

        //  onClick start scrolling the first carousel
        $t.click(function() {
            var d = ( $t.triggerHandler( 'currentPosition' ) == 0 ) ? i2+1 : 0;
            $org.trigger( 'slideTo', d );
        });

        //  set width + height
        $t.add( $d ).css({
            width: width / cols,
            height: height / rows
        });

        //  position images
        $d.children().css({
            left: -(col * (width / cols)),
            top: -(row * (height / rows))
        });
    });

    //  create carousels
    $all.carouFredSel({
        circular: false,
        items: {
            visible: 1,
            width: width / cols,
            height: height / rows
        },
        scroll: {
            fx: 'directscroll',
            onBefore: function() {
                var $t = $(this);

                //  trigger next carousel to scroll after 25 ms.
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $t.parent().next().children().trigger( 'slideTo', $t.triggerHandler( 'currentPosition' ) );
                }, 25);
            }
        }
    }).trigger( 'pause' );
});
```

Comment: isn't `$all` a just one element?

Comment: You should check the console, if you have not. (Many beginners do not know this, unfortunately.) It will often tell you problems. Hit F12 in the browser, and go to the console in dev tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/jquery" href="index.js"></script>
```

Hm.

```
text/jquery
```

jQuery is not a programming language, or even a MIME type. Use `text/javascript`, or just drop the `type` attribute altogether. Second, the name of the attribute specifying the location of the JavaScript is `src`, not `href`. (I make this mistake a lot, too, but if you look in the network panel and no request is being made, odds are it’s going to be one of these two problems. Or, in your case, both.)

It looks like you’ll need to include jQuery before it, too, so grab a copy from https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js, and include it with another `<script>` element.

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite new to HTML, thanks for telling me jQuery isnt a language, thats really useful. I will make sure to use src instead of href, and ill make sure to link jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

`<script type="text/jquery" href="index.js"></script>` is not valid.

If you are indeed using JQuery, you will need to import it with an additional `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

First replace `type="text/jquery"` by `type="text/javascript"`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<script type="text/javascript" href="index.js"></script>
```

if still your javascript file is not linking into html file it may have a problem with file PATH also.

Answer (score 0):

the **.js** file is in same folder or separate floder. if your .js file is in separate folder and html is in separate folder the you need to specify the absolute path of your **.js** file